# Recalculate sum of select option on change

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this selector with calculation on select change based on option sum id attribute and input number,
the problem is when im selecting option 1 and increase the input number is working just fine, but when i select option 2 or 3 and incrase the input number again the calculation of total sum is messing up. Im trying when i select different options if a change was made the total price to be again the one from option id.

```js
// Input number
 $('input[name=\'cantitate\']').on('change', function() {
      var cant  = $('#cantitate').val();
      var price = $(this).children(":selected").attr("id");
    $('#total').text(price * cant + ' USD');

  });
// Select box
 $('#variantacurs').on('change', function() {
       var cant  = $('#cantitate').val();
       var price = $(this).children(":selected").attr("id");
     $('#total').text(price * cant + ' USD');

  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="total">60</div>

  <select class="form-control" id="variantacurs" name="variantacurs">
    <option value="">---SELECT---</option>
     <option id="100" value="Option 1">Option 1</option>
     <option id="210" value="Option 2">Option 2</option>
     <option id="300" value="Option 3">Option 3</option>
  </select>

 <input type="number" name="cantitate" id="cantitate" placeholder="1" min="1" value="1" >
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Firstly, I recommend that you don't use the `id` attribute to store values for addition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a number of things wrong with this code:

1. The `id` tag is not a good way to store values. The values can be stored in the `value` attribute itself, whilst the label is the actual content of the `<option>` element. This makes it easier to retrieve values as well.
2. You can just define a function (eg. `calc()` in my example), and assign it's reference to `onchange` of the inputs instead of repeating code.
3. Use the `Number()` to convert the string input from `val()` into proper numbers.

Example:

```js
// Input number
$('input[name=\'cantitate\']').on('change', calc);
$('#variantacurs').on('change', calc);

function calc() {
      var cant = Number($('#cantitate').val());
      var price = Number($('#variantacurs').val());
      $('#total').text(cant * price + ' USD');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="total">60</div>

<select class="form-control" id="variantacurs" name="variantacurs">
  <option value="60" disabled selected>---SELECT---</option>
  <option value="100">Option 1</option>
  <option value="210">Option 2"</option>
  <option value="300">Option 3"</option>
</select>

<input type="number" name="cantitate" id="cantitate" placeholder="1" min="1" value="1">
```

Comment: Thanks to everyone for help, I want to mention: If I select an option and increase input number everything is ok so far, but if I change my mind and select another option why does the total actually increase in a wrong way and is not the actually the option value again?  and input number is not reset back to 1?

Comment: As of the input number not resetting back to 1, that's what my code, as well as yours and @xdeepakv code, is designed to do. The two values are independent unless othervise coded. Anyway, add this tag to the `select` element to get that behavior quickly: `onchange="$('#cantitate').val(1)"`. That should work.

Answer (score 0):

Typo, use .form-control selected input/select value.

`$(".form-control").children(":selected")`

```
$("input[name='cantitate']").on("change", function () {
  var cant = $("#cantitate").val();
  var price = $(".form-control").children(":selected").attr("id");
  console.log(price)
  $("#total").text(price * cant + " USD");
});
```

> I will recommend not to use id for value, use value as value. Some
>   clean can be done as below.

```js
(function ($) {
  // Input number
  const input = $("input[name='cantitate']");
  const select = $(".form-control");
  input.on("change", function () {
    calculate($(this).val(), select.children(":selected").val());
  });
  // Select box
  select.on("change", function () {
    calculate(input.val(), $(this).val());
  });
  function calculate(input, selected) {
    var cant = Number(input);
    var price = Number(selected);
    $("#total").text(`Total: ${price * cant + " USD"}`);
  }
})($);
```

```css
.as-console {
  min-height: 100% !important;
}

.as-console-row {
  color: blue !important;
}
```

```html
<div id="total">Total: 0</div>
    <select class="form-control" id="variantacurs" name="variantacurs">
        <option value="">---SELECT---</option>
        <option value="100">Option 1</option>
        <option value="200">Option 2</option>
        <option value="300">Option 3</option>
    </select>
    <input type="number" name="cantitate" placeholder="1" min="1" value="1">
    <script
    src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"
    integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo="
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```