# Show total based on multiple input using php and mysql

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I want to show total price from selected products + its quantity. Example: I choose Product 1 for 2 pcs and  Product 2 for 3 pcs. Product 1's price is 15000 and Product 2's price 4000. So, if Product 1 is 2 pcs = 15000 * 2 = 30000. And Product 2 is 3 pcs = 4000 * 3 = 12000.
The problem is i just can show the total of first selected product (In this case, the first selected product = Product 1 (2pcs) = 30000). Like this:
[image]

The code:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xl-6 col-md-6 col-12 mb-1">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="product_id">Produk</label>
            <select class="form-control" name="product_id[]" id="product_id">
                <option value="">Pilih</option>
                <?php
                    $sql = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM product ORDER BY id ASC");
                    while($data = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)){
                ?>
                <option value="<?php echo $data['id']; ?>"><?php echo $data['name']; ?></option>
                <?php } ?>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xl-6 col-md-6 col-12 mb-1">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="total_product">Jumlah Produk</label>
            <input type="number" class="form-control" name="total_product[]" id="total_product" placeholder="Jumlah" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#total_product').on('keyup', function(){
            var data_total = $('#product_id').val(); 
            var total_product = $('#total_product').val(); 
            console.log(data_total);
            $.ajax({
                type: 'get',
                url: 'ajax-total.php',
                data: {
                    'data_total': data_total,
                    'total_product': total_product,
                },
                success: function(data){
                    var json = data,        
                    obj = JSON.parse(json);
                    console.log(data);
                    $('#total').val(obj.total);        
                }
            });
        });
    })
</script>
```

```
<?php
    include '../koneksi.php';

    $data_total = $_GET['data_total'];
    $total_product = $_GET['total_product'];
    $query = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT sale_price FROM product WHERE id='$data_total'");
    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query);

    $total = (int)$row['sale_price'] * (int)$total_product;

    $data = array(
            'total'   =>   $total);
            
     echo json_encode($data);
?>
```

How to calculate all the price from all selected product and show it with ajax?

Comment: Are you having a specific problem when you run this code currently? Please explain your issue as well as just your objective.

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61023075/6670570) answer your question?

Comment: @ADyson the problem is the code on,y shows the total price of the first selected product. meanwhile the second and more is note calculated. so how to calculate all the selected product?

Comment: The code you have shown us is just for one drop-down, but you have many drop-downs in the page, is that correct? If so then Matts' suggestion is correct, it is only working with the first item because IDs must be unique to each element, and you must have multiple elements with the ID "total_product". By definition, ID can only identify one thing. So jQuery ignores all the others with the same ID because they aren't valid. Use a class selector instead to bind the event handler to all the inputs

Comment: @ADyson ya, that's right. that's my problem. i still have no idea how to get all the selected product's price in array and then calculate all of them and show it in 'total' using ajax. i mean how to select the multiple value so i could send it to other file to calculate it in php? currect code is onlye get one value from one dropdown. i know i have change the selector from id to class/element. but i still did'nt get it to implement it even i have check Matts's suggestion

Comment: Well again, `$('#total_product').val()` will only get the value from the first one. Same for `$('#product_id').val()`. if these items are all part of the same form you should use use jQuery serialize() to automatically collect all the values from the form, that would solve your problem with one line of code

Comment: I'm under the impression there is actually 2 issues here. First you need to find how to collect data from all dropdown menus (a JQuery/Javascript question), second you'll have to find how to send/receive data to/from PHP (an AJAX/REST question).